# Можно ли в энтерпрайз проекте заменить Java на Scala?

Tags: java, java-ee, scala

Есть проект написанный на Java EE. Можно-ли в проект добавить Scala? Что ждет? Выйдут ли баги о несовместимости?

Comment: Можно. Какой реальный ответ вы хотели получить?

Comment: @Хотел бы узнать можно ли так делать или этого делать не стоит ?

Comment: можно/не можно и стоит/не стоит - это две большие разницы. Можно ли - да, можно. Нужно ли? это вопрос к менеджеру (или заказчику). стоит ли? нет, не стоит. Иначе уже бы давно попробовали.

Comment: Багов с совместимостью не будет, платформа-то одна, а вот затраты на поддержку увеличатся, так как в проекте станет на один язык больше.